# Conditioning versus subscripting for a Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, notation

I tried to see if this question had been asked anywhere, but it's a bit hard to set up the search terms properly.

I want to confirm my a priori notion that the notations $P_{X_\tau}[G]$ and $P[G|X_\tau]$ do indeed denote different things, where $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a Markov process and $\tau$ is a stopping time. I'm having to question myself just because I've recently come across some papers which cast my notion into doubt.

To say a bit more, I interpret $P[G|X_\tau]$ in the classical sense as just a r.v. measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(X_\tau)$ and having the property
$$
  \int_H P[G|X_\tau] dP
= \int_H I_G dP
= P[G \cap H]
$$
for all $\sigma(X_\tau)$-measurable sets $H$, and
$P_{X_\tau}[G]$ as the composition of the function 
$$
   f(x) 
:= P[G|X_0 = x]
$$
with the r.v. $X_\tau$. Although $P_{X_\tau}[G]$ certainly satisfies the measurability condition, the integral condition seems not to hold generally: 
$$
  \int_H P_{X_\tau}[G] dP
= \mathbb{E}[I_H (\mathbb{E}[G|X_0 = \cdot]\circ X_\tau)]
= \overset{?}{\dots}
= P[G \cap H].
$$
And of course, when I say that I'd thought they denote different things, I really mean non-equivalent entities.

Thanks a hundred!

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did Could you show a simple example of a process $X$ and a stopping time $\tau$ such that the last equality doesn't hold? I got confused trying to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the integral condition seems not to hold generally

Indeed it does not.

Example: consider $X$ a Brownian motion starting at $0$, $\tau=\inf\{T_2,T_{-2}\}$ where, for every $x$, $T_x=\inf\{t\geqslant0\mid X_t=x\}$, $G=[T_1\gt T_3]$ and $H=\Omega$.

Then $P(G\cap H)=P(G)=0$ while $P_2(G)=\frac12$ and $P_{-2}(G)=0$ hence $P_{X_\tau}(G)=\frac12\mathbf 1_{X_\tau=2}$ and $E(\mathbf 1_HP_{X_\tau}(G))=\frac12P(X_\tau=2)=\frac14$.

Comment: Very nice! This is just what I was expecting.